# How to exclude {} in a field from a search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a record like

```json
"log": {
      "Level": null,
      "Message": "blah",
      "StackTrace": "{}"
}
```

I have tried something like

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must_not": [{
                "match": {
                    "log.StackTrace": {
                        "query": "{}",
                        "type": "phrase"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }

    }
}
```

But still can't exclude this record from the search result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a term query inside the must_not clause and use log.StackTrace.Keyword as the field

```
{ "query": { "bool": { "must_not": { "term" { "log.StackTrace.keyword": "{}" } } }}
```

Comment: Thank you! keyword is the key!